# How to run a floating bubble as a background service , put all the bubble code inside OnStart method

Tags: java, android

This is the Background Service.java code which contains the `onStart()` method-

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    private void addNewBubble () // Error here , says missing token ';' and Expression Expected

    {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        //here is all the science of params
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout) LayoutInflater.from(BackgroundService.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
        bubbleView.setLayoutParams(myParams);

        bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {


                Bitmap b = Screenshot.takescreenshotOfRootView(imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
                main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked !",
                //   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
        bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
    }
}

private void initializeBubblesManager() {
    bubblesManager = new BubblesManager.Builder(this)
            .setTrashLayout(R.layout.bubble_trash_layout)
            .setInitializationCallback(new OnInitializedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized() {
                    addNewBubble(); // Cannot resolve this method
                }
            })
            .build();
    bubblesManager.initialize();
}
```

The MainActivity only contains the permissions code to run the floating bubble , with the checkDrawOverlay() method , with the
 startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
in its else part....

Comment: I am trying to run the floating bubble so that it can take a screenshot of the screen while using any other application on the phone. This is why I am trying to Implement the background service. https://github.com/yohanelly/Floating-Bubble-Live-Screenshots

Comment: I think it means its not a valid code format. Take a close look at where the methods are starting and ending.

Comment: I put the entire floating bubble code into the onStart() method , and only the addNewBubble method gives an error. Also , to create a background service i dont need to create a whole new blank activity right?

Comment: @n247s Could you give me any suggestions as to how to check where there is an error in regards to the starting or ending of the method? I have been stuck on this one error for two days now. Someone else's perspective would really help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid code format which is why your IDE is complaining about a missing semicolon(`;`). with the sentence;

> "Take a close look at where the methods are starting and ending"

I meant that you need to pay attention to where you declare methods, as they may only be declared in the scope of a Class declaration. Currently you are declaring a method in the scope of another method (not valid). e.g.

```
public void methodOne()
{
    // this nested method declaration is considerd invalid
    private void methodTwo()
    {
        // method content
    }
}
```

to fix it simply do

```
public void methodOne()
{
    // call other method if you need it to be executed here
    methodTwo();
}

private void methodTwo()
{
    // method content
}
```

this will take care of both the `missing semicolon error` and the `cannot resolve method error`.

Comment: Thanks for that. The errors have gone, now there are no errors. Although when I run the App , and click on Add Bubble button. The Floating Bubble does not get created at all. I checked the Android Monitor and it shows no errors. Why is that? Did i need to create a separate blank activity for the BackgroundService.java?

Comment: Hey so I have figured it out. Although I have a question, To take a screenshot of the current activity of the user do you have to use MediaProjection only? Or is there another way using the DrawingCache. I have created a Floating Bubble which I want to be able to take a screenshot of the current activity the user is on. Any suggestions?